# Failed to find a usable hardware address from the network interfaces

Tags: clojure, docker, netty, aleph

I'm getting the following warning when running Aleph (which uses Netty) as a websever inside a Docker container:

```
WARNING: Failed to find a usable hardware address from the network interfaces; using random bytes: 75:62:7f:9b:c6:52:63:4b
```

I'm starting the server using:

```
(defn -main [& args]
  (http/start-server app {:port 3000}))
```

And I've also tried:

```
(defn -main [& args]
  (http/start-server app {:socket-address (java.net.InetSocketAddress. "0.0.0.0" 3000)}))
```

but still I get the same warning.

The warning **only** happens inside a docker container. I can run the server in my host without the warning. I also won't get the warning if when I run the container I use `docker run --net host webserver`.

The really weird thing is, despite the warning everything looks to be running fine. The correct ports are bound and the server is running correctly. Does anyone have any idea why I get this warning?

Comment: This seems to be a [known bug](https://github.com/netty/netty/issues/3490), closed back in May.  At least, that looks like it is probably the same issue.

Comment: Thanks, that does look like the same issue. It would fit as well since Aleph is using netty-4.1.0-beta4 and that issue has been merged in netty-4.1.0-beta5

Comment: This pull request updates the Netty version to 4.1.0.Beta6, which is the one that actually contains the fix https://github.com/ztellman/aleph/pull/175